# Give users access to all user's data in dashboard

Tags: permissions, user, dashboard

I am working on a dashboard that allows users to see the number of tasks that are assigned for the day. The dashboard works great but when I view it as a user I can only see the tasks that are assigned to that particular person. What can I do so everyone can see the full dashboard (number of assigned tasks by user for all users)?

Answer (score 0):

Check the OWD setting on Activity. If it is controlled by parent , then you have to open up the access of the parent object.  Say for example all these tasks are related to Object A , then make sure that this object A is is visible to all intended users.

If the OWD is private , create a simple sharing rule to increase the visibility of all tasks across the intended users.

But make sure you **do not compromise the security of data** ( per option A), if its not intended that you share parent object , then we can think of some other way.

Comment: thanks for your help, right now anyone is able to work a task even though they might not be the owner. So I was trying option A, Activity is now set to "Controled by parent". I am assuming the parent is Accounts (these are tasks on an account) which is set to "Public Read/Write". still no other users tasks are showing on the dashboard.

Comment: or and I forgot to say I am trying the sharing rule now.

Comment: I think I figured it out, the report I was basing the dashboard on was set to "my team's" tasks by default. I am going to create an answer for this post, but thanks for your help! I learned something new.

Comment: Yeah thats good. Ta

Answer (score 0):

it turns out that when creating a activity/ task report the drop down for "show" is defaulted to "my team" , I changed it to "all activities" and everything seems to work.